# HTML Canvas draw image from database

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to get an image from my database, and show it in a canvas and draw shapes on it. Is there a way to draw image on canvas using image as byte array etc..

Answer (score -1):

A `<canvas>` is like a regular `<img>` image with the difference that the Javascript code of the page can actually control the values of the pixels.

You can decide what is the content of the canvas by drawing primitives like lines, polygons, arcs or even other images. You can also set or alter the content by processing the actual red, green, blue and transparency values of every single pixel (using `getImageData` and `putImageData`). You can resize the canvas as you wish and drawing on a canvas is quite fast... fast enough to be able to do complex animations with just plain Javascript code.

For example the code to load an image and draw it in a canvas after changing it to black and white and adding a red grid could be:

```
function canvasTest(img) {
    let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // Copy image pixels to the canvas
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    // Now let's set R and B channels equal to G
    let idata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (let i=0,n=img.width*img.height*4; i<n; i+=4) {
        idata.data[i] = idata.data[i+2] = idata.data[i+1];
    }
    ctx.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);

    // Add a red grid
    ctx.beginPath();
    for (let y=0; y<img.height; y+=50) {
        ctx.moveTo(0, y+0.5); ctx.lineTo(img.width, y+0.5);
    }
    for (let x=0; x<img.width; x+=50) {
        ctx.moveTo(x+0.5, 0); ctx.lineTo(x+0.5, img.height);
    }
    ctx.strokeStyle = "#F00";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.stroke();

    // add the final result to page
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
}
```

The only annoyance is that if you draw an image on a canvas and the image is coming from a different origin from where the page comes from, then the canvas becomes in the general case "tainted" and you cannot access the pixel values any more (`getImageData` is forbidden). The reason for this limit is security (and the sad fact that security in web application is on the client). In your case since the image database is yours there should be no problem.

Comment: @Kaiido: true... i was in a hurry. I've added a simple example of code working both at pixel level and using drawing primitives.